# Does Javascript have the distinction of page forward and page redirect?

Tags: javascript, jsf

JSF ensure

```
<h:commandXxx action="index.xhtml">
```

to page forward, and

```
<h:commandXxx action="index.xhtml?facesredirect=true">
```

to page redirect.

How to perform these two operations with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Just send a request to server in such way that the server applies exactly the desired behavior.

E.g.

```
location = "index.xhtml";
```

```
location = "pageWhichRedirectsToOtherPageWhichForwardsToThatPage.xhtml";
```